# How does globalization culture affect MVC Dates

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following model:

```
public class Appointment
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

view:

```
@model ModelValidation.Models.Appointment
Appointment Date: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
```

and controller:

```
public ViewResult MakeBooking()
{
    return View(new Appointment { Date = DateTime.Now });
}
```

I've added this to Web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    ...
    <globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU"/>
  </system.web>
```

This results in the following HTML body:

```
Appointment Date: <input class="text-box single-line" 
data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." 
data-val-required="The Date field is required." 
id="Date" name="Date" type="date" value="25/09/2018" />
```

The textbox on the page looks like this:

[image]

My first question is, why does it display "dd/mm/yyyy" instead of "25/09/2018"?

When I change `<globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU"/>` to `<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>` the only difference is that the HTML generates `value="09/25/2018"` instead of `value="25/09/2018"`
Why does it not then display "mm/dd/yyyy" in the textbox on the webpage?

I am using MVC5 and Chrome and am located in Australia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute generates `type="date"` when used with `EditorFor()` which in turn generates the browsers HTML5 datepicker.

The HTML specifications require that the the date be in ISO format, so you need to add a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and the date will then be displayed in the users culture (which is the purpose of of the HTML5 datepicker).

Alternatively, you can use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")
```

Comment: I noticed that ApplyFormatInEditMode = true changes the textbox to display "26/09/2018" instead of "dd/mm/yyyy". However I would have expected it to show "2018-09-26". How can I make it show the date in different formats? Btw the HTML is showing the expected date format: value="2018-09-26"

Comment: The purpose of the HTML5 datepicker is to display/edit dates in the users culture (so you cannot unless you have the user change the culture on their device). If you want a consistent UI across all broswers, then its better to use a jQuery datepicker plugin